# Voice Control Turtlesim ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 20.04 with Pocketsphinx

Tags: ros-humble, turtlesim, pocketsphinx, ubuntu-20.04, speech-processing

I want to use Pocketsphinx on my ROS2 workspace, but wanted to try it out on Turtlesim first. While building my workspace with

`colcon build --packages-select pocketsphinx_package`

I alwalys get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pocketsphinx" with
  any of the following names:

    pocketsphinxConfig.cmake
    pocketsphinx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pocketsphinx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "pocketsphinx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "pocketsphinx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

I installed pocketsphinx using the follwing commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install pocketsphinx`

Comment: Where did you find ROS 2 pocketsphinx bindings?

All I could find is ros-pocketsphinx which is not compatible with ROS 2.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even check if it was compatible with ROS2! So I can't use pocketsphinx? Do you know another speech recognizer I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not installed the development files for this library. Use `apt` to search for an apt package named something like `pocketsphinx-dev` and install it.

Comment: I searched for it and `libpocketsphinx-dev` is already installed. I also tried to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the right path, but I still get the same error.